# Obtaining postcode using Python 2.7 in Alexa Skill

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, alexa-skills-kit

So I've managed to build my first Alexa skill and testing it on my Echo, it works well with the returned responses working well.

I'm now looking to expand my device's capabilities and I want to obtain the postcode associated with the device settings. I've enabled access to this as part of my skill creation and I've read that you can't test this functionality as part of the skill creation and you have to test it direct on your device.

Below is my code to obtain the postcode:-

```
def get_postcode(intent, session):
    session_attributes = {}
    reprompt_text = None

    URL =  "https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v1/devices/{}/settings" \
           "/address".format(context.System.device.deviceId)
    TOKEN =  context.System.user.permissions.consentToken
    HEADER = {'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(TOKEN)}
    response = urllib2.urlopen(URL, headers=HEADER)
    data = json.load(response)

    speech_output = "Your postcode is " + data['postalCode'] 
    should_end_session = True

    return build_response(session_attributes, build_speechlet_response(
        intent['name'], speech_output, reprompt_text, should_end_session))
```

Unfortunately, whenever I test this, I receive a response from my Echo that "there is a problem with the returned response"

Any suggestions? I feel that my skill is calling the correct intent but the lambda isn't processing the function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> This function returns a file-like object with three additional methods:
>
> ```
> geturl() — return the URL of the resource retrieved, commonly used to determine if a redirect was followed
> info() — return the meta-information of the page, such as headers, in the form of an mimetools.Message instance (see Quick Reference to HTTP Headers)
> getcode() — return the HTTP status code of the response.
> ```

Edit your Question and show the Output of the following:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(URL, headers=HEADER)
print(response.geturl())
print(response.info())
print(response.getcode())
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

While requesting the device address you need to provide the `apiAccessToken` in the Authorization field. But it seems like you are providing the `consentToken`.

```
def get_postcode(intent, session):
        session_attributes = {}
        reprompt_text = None

        URL =  "https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v1/devices/{}/settings" \
               "/address".format(context.System.device.deviceId)

        # TOKEN =  context.System.user.permissions.consentToken
        # replace this by
        TOKEN =  context.System.apiAccessToken

        HEADER = {'Accept': 'application/json',
                 'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(TOKEN)}
        response = urllib2.urlopen(URL, headers=HEADER)
        data = json.load(response)

        speech_output = "Your postcode is " + data['postalCode'] 
        should_end_session = True

        return build_response(session_attributes, build_speechlet_response(
            intent['name'], speech_output, reprompt_text, should_end_session))
```

You also need to make sure that you are granting the permission in your alexa app to access the device address. Once you have done that, you are good to go.